# Getting uncategorized objects in has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

Good day all,

Pardon me for my noob-ness in rails.

So here's my question.

So I've a category model and a itinerary model defined below

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :itineraries, :through => :categorizations
end

class Itinerary < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
end
```

So in my view, I am looping through categories to display itineraries in groups.

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4"><%= category.name %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% category.itineraries.each do |itinerary| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= itinerary.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', itinerary %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_itinerary_path(itinerary) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', itinerary, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<% end %>
```

So I am wondering, how do we display itineraries that are not categorised yet?
I've searched around and found out that using scopes in the model will be the way to go.

```
scope :without_categories, -> { includes(:categorizations).where( :categorizations => { :itinerary_id => nil } )}
```

I find it not very "DRY" due to the fact that I've to write another table to iterate through `itinerary.without_categories` again.

Is there a way where we're able to code it in such a way where `categories.all` shows everything with `uncategorized` items in it?

Thank you.

## Update #1

Decided to use this in my controller, which builds a new "Uncategorized" category on index action and it'll add to the array.

```
def index
  uncategorized = Category.new
  uncategorized.name = "Uncategorized";
  uncategorized.itineraries = Itinerary.without_categories
  @categories = Category.all << uncategorized
end
```

I know that in rails, controllers should be as skinny as possible.
But I can't think of a better way.

Anyone with a better answer, please feel free to share. Thanks! :)

Comment: From the question, perhaps you should be using Itineraries as the basis of your table, include the associated category, and sort by Category name -- create a break/header every time the category changes, with a default break/header for those non-categorized Itineraries. Should be a simple 1 pass through Itineraries.

Comment: Hi @railsdog, thank you for your time.
I've thought of that too, but in my itineraries can have many categories. Hence I think there would be conflicts right?

Comment: Ugh, yeah I missed that in my initial read. I'd probably resort to a find_by_sql with (if memory serves) some left joins and a final sort to assemble the data I wanted in the desired order. Databases excel at some things, so why not put them to work, and hide those data marshaling details behind a model method.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to find the itineraries that dont have a reference inside the Categorizations table. You can do a nested query for this.

`SELECT * FROM itineraries where id NOT IN ( SELECT itinerary_id FROM categorizations')`

just do a method in your Itinerary model like this:

```
def self.uncategorized
  Itinerary.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM itineraries where id NOT IN ( SELECT itinerary_id FROM categorizations)')
end
```